# How to change the url of page based on selectbox values?

Tags: php

I have php search filter page in which i used different fields..One of them is Age of youngest driver field which have 2 values like 21-24 and 25+ ..Basically i only want to keep the selected values in the select box even after search so user know what he searched for ..What happen now when i select 25+ from the field and click on search it goes back to 21-24 . But As page is connected top database so it picks values from database which i enter like the database screenshot below Please check and let me know if it have any solution

```
  <select class="half" id="form_frame" name=""  onsubmit="getData(this);"/>
  <option id="value1"  value="21-24" selected="selected">21-24</option>
  <option id="value2" value="25+">25+</option>
  </select>
```

When i slect all values from the field and selct 25+ from driver age field then url is

http://localhost/Vehicle2/?car_type=0&pickup=0&return=0&residence_two=International&driver_age=25%2B&passengers=No.+of+Passengers&search=

http://localhost/Vehicle2/?car_type=0&pickup=0&return=0&residence_two=International&driver_age=21-24&passengers=No.+of+Passengers&search=

I want driverage=21-24 instead of driver_age

Comment: Please put full form code.

Comment: @Ankit Solanki  What you need fro me ? DO you want to see full code

Comment: Just full form code.

Comment: Use JavaScript to add query parameter to URL. Then make isset on that in your PHP, get it's value and show content depending on that variable.

Comment: @ Ankit Solanki PLease check updated question in 5 min

Comment: @AnkitSolanki please check theupdate question and database screenshot here

Answer (score 0):

Apply `onchange` event in javascript like as follows  if you are using jquery

```
 jQuery(function () {
        jQuery("#form_frame").change(function () {
            var id = jQuery(this).val();;
            location.href = "http://localhost/php-page/option"+id+"="+id

        })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple use change event handler for selectbox

```js
$(document).on('change','#form_frame',function(){

//window.location.href="http://localhost/php-//page/option"+$(this).//val()+"="$(this).val();

console.log("http://localhost/phppage/option"+$(this).val()+"="+$(this).val());



});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="half" id="form_frame" name="">
 <option  value="10" selected="selected">10</option>
 <option value="11">11</option>
 </select>
```